# MSBuild error while compiling ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net

I get the following error when I try to compile an asp.net site using a custom build script.

```
error ASPCONFIG: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.
```

Although the description is in detail I do not understand what it means exactly. I have not configured IIS to host this website and I don't think I will be able to as I am running Vista Home Basic version. So the website cannot be built using custom scripts?Please reply as I want to test this feature.

Comment: I too was deleting the obj folder until I had a conflict with a build script which required it. Catch-22, I used the accepted answer on the following SO link to move the location of the Obj folder to C:\Temp\BUILD. You have to do it per csproj file, but it is a great solution. Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261422/visualstudio-how-to-save-the-obj-folder-somewhere-else

Comment: possible duplicate of [allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' msbuild error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271320/allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-msbuild-error)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is likely that your web.config file is placed in a directory that is not the root of the application.  On most versions of IIS, you can convert any folder on your web site to an application root:

1. Open IIS and navigate to the appropriate folder
2. Right-click on the folder, select properties
3. Under Application Settings, and beside Application name, click **Create**
4. Apply and close

If this does not fix your problem, there may be another configuration error, either with IIS or your application.

Answer (score 48):

I had this SAME EXACT problem and finally discovered a rogue Web.config was placed in my obj folder ... do yourself a favor and do a search in all the sub-directories for a web.config file. I deleted it and all was back to normal.

Comment: Thanks, that did the solved the problem for me.I had the same problem. I deleted the object\debug folder and it worked again.

Comment: +1 - Nice, thanks. Another note, if you create the backup folder within your project when converting, you will need to remove/rename the web.config there too.

Comment: thanks! this was driving me crazy for hours.  my stray web.config was in the /views folder.  *sigh*

Comment: @Patricia that's normal for ASP.NET MVC - it's more likely a web.config in the obj folder created by doing a Publish

Comment: @DanielO -- I tried to upvote your comment, as it is precisely the problem I had.  Publish was indeed the source of the problem.

Comment: Thanks! I also managed to find one in my bin\ folder, as it was indicated in the csproj file as the OutputPath.

Comment: Had the same problem. Did this :) `for /F %i in ('dir obj /s /b') do del /s /q %i`

Comment: I only received this error when scanning with HP Fortify. The fix worked.

Comment: Thanks! This was driving me nuts all week. Turns out it happened when I optimistically switched to VS 2017 for a few days. Back to 2015 now and extremely wary.

Answer (score 15):

The rogue web.config file in the obj folder is most likely to be caused when you do a Publish Web Site. So just clean it up after you've done the publish.

Answer (score 5):

if this happens after the virtual-directory is already created do the following:

- right-click on web.config

  - properties

    - Build Action: Content
    - Copy to Output directory: Do not copy
- if transformed (apply to all configurations)

  - properties

    - Build Action: None
    - Copy to Output directory: Do not copy

Comment: The first option worked fine for me, even though I have web config transformations.

Comment: Man, this issue tripped me up for so long. This was the issue!

Answer (score 0):

In IIS, go to the folder that the app runs under, right click it, go to properties.
On the Directory tab, look for "Application settings".  Click the create button.