# allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' msbuild error

Tags: msbuild, web-config

We have a ASP.NET MVC with 4-5 different build configurations. Whenever we change the build configuration, we need to delete the obj folder for the web project, since we get the 'allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' error. A pain, but we managed by deleting the folder in pre/post build events. 
Now I need to configure our CI to build deployment packages. This means that I cannot delete the obj folder. Every time I compile e.g. with the following msbuild parameters

> /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true

I recieve the error:

> web.config(123): error ASPCONFIG: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

As far as I understand, the problem is that there's multiple .config files in the project - In our case, there's not. I could really use some help to find an explanation and find a permanent (no- hack) fix.

Edit:
This question is marked as a duplicate, but the corresponding answers and cause(s) in the 2 threads, are clearly different from each other. Not sure what is intended with this tag - I've read that particular post before posting this question, as it didn't answer my question. There's multiple causes for this error message. It is 'similar', but definitely not a duplicate!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I too was deleting the obj folder until I had a conflict with a build script which required it. Catch-22, I used the accepted answer on the following SO link to move the location of the Obj folder to `C:\Temp\BUILD`. You have to do it per csproj file, but it is a great solution.

Here is the link: [VisualStudio: How to save the obj folder somewhere else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261422/visualstudio-how-to-save-the-obj-folder-somewhere-else)

Note that I am using a variable for the project name.
R:\Temp\Build\Debug\$(MSBuildProjectName)

I have the above line in both debug and release sections for all my projects, including class projects. My build path is a ram drive for speed. See this SO for more info: [How to access macro variables within csproj file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174614/how-to-access-macro-variables-within-csproj-file)

Comment: Thanks for this link. The exact cause of my problem was that my web.config contains an `<authorization>` section and the web.config was copied to `obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp` during build. The publisher somehow recognized that web.config as a subdirectory web.config and complained that `<authorization>` is defined in a web.config that's not in an application directory.

Comment: The answer I this issue fixed my problem (I was building the MVC views as part of the build)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221503/teamcity-build-failure

Answer (score 25):

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2566215/64096) here on SO with some good solutions for this issue.

The problem is that building a deployment package creates a copy of the web.config in a subfolder of /obj. That will normally be be cleared out if you do a rebuild or a clean. However, if you build a deployment package in one configuration (e.g. Debug) and then switch to another confguration (e.g. Release) the obj/Debug folder is not cleared out and the web.config file there causes problems.

The quick solution is to clean *all* configurations and then do a (re)build. Alternatively you could delete the /obj folder in your project.
To permanently resolve the issue you can either move the intermediate output (/obj) out of your project folder or modify the project to force a clean of all configurations on rebuild.

Comment: This seems like a bug with the compiler. I added a pre-build event to delete the obj folder. Its a hack, but it works.

Comment: Very effective. I extended the clean target but this is actually simpler to do. Not sure I'd call this a compiler bug though. The aspnet compiler should exclude the /obj folder, that would prevent this from happening. Either that or the deployment packaging pipeline should not (ab)use the /obj folder for it's output.

Comment: Deleting the obj folder seems to work for VS builds, but not for command line web deploy.  I tried Phil Haack's solution to no avail as well.  :(

Answer (score 12):

I just answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8346680/210774).  To recap, I ran into this problem in one of our MVC projects, and it was due to having the `MvcBuildViews` property in the project file set to `true`. Setting the property to `false` fixed the problem.

```xml
<MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews>
```

I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2862996/210774) which outlines an alternative that does not require turning off view building.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that there is an "official" fix as it just seemed to start on multiple projects of mine for no reason that I can find in Visual Studio Premium 2012 (never happened in previous versions of VS).

As a work around to automate the deletion of the obj directory as others have said, similar to an answer by user Casual in this post [VisualStudio: How to save the obj folder somewhere else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261422/visualstudio-how-to-save-the-obj-folder-somewhere-else), where unfortunately just moving the location of the obj folder didn't always seem to work.

Instead I added a few commands under Build Events in the Pre-build event command line:

```
rd "$(ProjectDir)obj" /S /Q
md "$(ProjectDir)obj"
md "$(ProjectDir)obj\Debug"
md "$(ProjectDir)obj\Release"
```

You can change/add/remove subfolders to match your custom build configurations using the line where buildConfigName matches the name of the build configuration you are using:

```
md "$(ProjectDir)obj\buildConfigName"
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

That error indicates that you are trying to something specific to an application at an IIS tree level that isn't defined as an application.  For example if you try to do app-level functions in a web.config in a virtual directory, you will get that error.  You need to find the path you are deploying to and make sure that it is defined in IIS as an application vs a folder or vdir.

Comment: Nevermind the deploy on build part. I just want to create a deployment package. I've tried locally to create a deployement package using the following cli parameters: msbuild Web.csproj /t:Package /P:Configuration=Test;PackageLocation="c:\temp\somepackagename.zip"  However the same result. Note the project is not hooked into IIS (using embedded casini webserver) and hence this cannot be a IIS configuration error. If I delete the obj folder prior building, the problem goes away.

Answer (score 1):

Cleaning the solution (Right click Solution in VS, clean), worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error but with a deployed page.. Then realized my webserver's clock was set back to 2010 for some reason.  set it to the correct date fix my problem

Answer (score 1):

Clean your project
Remove the /obj folder (probably using publish and deploy? - there is a bug in it)

Answer (score 1):

Althoug the problem is explained and solved in one way in the accepted answer, I wanted to show a solution which can be better for other cases. This solution has been included in some version of VS, but I can only say that I had the problem in VS 2013 Update 5. (See the *"Beware"* below, it could be fixed in this version, but not working only in my particular case).

I borrowed the soltuion from [Error: allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level on Visual Studio Connect.](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/779737/error-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyond-application-level)

The solution consist in including these lines to the web application project (`.csproj` file) which handle the deletion of the offedning intermediate files (which wans't a solution for the accepted answer, as he needed those intermediate files):

```
<!--Deal with http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/779737/error-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyond-application-level, 
we will need to clean up our temp folder before MVC project starts the pre-compile-->
<PropertyGroup>
    <_EnableCleanOnBuildForMvcViews Condition=" '$(_EnableCleanOnBuildForMvcViews)'=='' ">true</_EnableCleanOnBuildForMvcViews>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="CleanupForBuildMvcViews" Condition=" '$(_EnableCleanOnBuildForMvcViews)'=='true' and '$(MVCBuildViews)'=='true' " BeforeTargets="MvcBuildViews">
    <ItemGroup>
     <_PublishTempFolderNamesToCleanup Include="Database;TransformWebConfig;CSAutoParameterize;InsertAdditionalCS;ProfileTransformWebConfig;Package;AspnetCompileMerge" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <!--Force msbuild to expand all the wildcard characters so to get real file paths-->
    <CreateItem Include="@(_PublishTempFolderNamesToCleanup->'$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)**\%(identity)\**\*')">
     <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="_EvaluatedPublishTempFolderNamesToCleanup" />
    </CreateItem>
    <Delete Files="@(_EvaluatedPublishTempFolderNamesToCleanup)" />
</Target>
```

**Beware:** for some reason, probably because I included it myself in the project, my build target for building the views was named `"BuildViews"`, instead of `"MvcBuildViews"`, so I had to modify the `BeforeTargets` attribute accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is not necessarily the exact same issue, and to be honest, probably down to pure lack of knowledge on my part, however I had this same error when:

1. I set up a standard asp.net new project actually just used for HTML5 stuff so nothing other than the usual project structure
2. I then (not thinking perhaps!) added a new WCF REST project (which actually was just another base asp.net project using very good examples from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128478/Consuming-WCF-REST-Services-Using-jQuery-AJAX-Call?fid=1597004&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=26#xx0xx  and http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/08/21/restful-wcf-services-with-no-svc-file-and-no-config.aspx

The problem was I added the WCF REST project (#2) as a SUB-DIRECTORY of the main project (#1) and then tried to build! even if I cleaned the project of course.. I also made both projects use IISexpress because I thought there was an issue using the same port or something.

Of course the build process saw the web.config from #1 and then a sub-dir with another web.config #2..

I realise this probably should be a very basic understood *gotcha* and it has caught me out a while ago, however sometimes it's the simplest of mistakes that are a real pain!

Might help others... who perhaps haven't had their morning coffee..

Answer (score 0):

tip 1: clean & then rebuild.

tip 2: just close VS and open again.

tip 3: the downloaded project may be inside another sub folder... open the folder which has you .net files.

c:/demo1/demo/ (all files)

You should have to open demo from vs... not demo1.

Answer (score 0):

I have a somewhat a similar problem, i had the main config as **Copy Always** so it copied the config to the bin directory. When i republished the main project, i got the MachineToApplication error. So my solution was to just change the config to **Do Not Copy** and remove the extra configuration in the bin folder.