# How to access macro variables within csproj file?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, csproj

In my csproj file, I have a different build path.

```
<BaseIntermediateOutputPath>C:\Temp\Build\MyProject</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
```

When in the prebuild and post build events, I have access to certain macro variables.

```
$(OutDir)
$(ProjectName)
$(ProjectPath)
$(SolutionDir)
```

Can I use those variables within my csproj?

For example, I tried the following without success.

```
<BaseIntermediateOutputPath>C:\Temp\Build\$(ProjectName)</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar requirement and using $(MSBuildProjectName) did the job for me.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectView>ProjectFiles</ProjectView>
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>R:\$(MSBuildProjectName)\obj\</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Here R: is my RAMDISK drive letter.

For others who may also face issues in setting up the RAMDISK drive letter correctly, I used a simple VBS script

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colVolumes = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_Volume") Where Label = 'RAMDISK'")
For Each objVolume in colVolumes
    objVolume.DriveLetter = "R:"
    objVolume.Put_
Next
```

This ensures that any drive loaded with the label RAMDISK is set to R: drive instead of the default drive that appears. While this is not part of your Q, I am sure that this will be handy to others who have similar requirements of using the RAMDISK for their obj files and find the case of changing drive letters in vbproj/csproj files cumbersome.

#### References:

1. Reserved properties: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164309%28loband%29.aspx
2. Changing drive letters: http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/disk/drives/

Comment: thank you. Also, cheers for the ram drive trick. Have set one up to increase build speed.

Comment: It works dramatically!! May I emphasize you must use `$(MSBuildProjectName)` rather than $(ProjectName).