# ASP.net MVC 4 project with simple membership, Publishing Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, publishing, iis-express

I am getting the following error when I am trying to publish my website:

> It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication'
>
> beyond application level. This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being
>
> configured as an application in IIS

and below in the same page:

```
Ligne 31 :     <compilation targetFramework="4.5"/>
Ligne 32 :     <httpRuntime/>
Ligne 33 :     <authentication mode="Forms">
Ligne 34 :       <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880"/>
Ligne 35 :     </authentication>
```

I am using Visual Studio 2012 IIS express and already created a virtual directory in the project properties page, and deactivated the web.config file in the Views folder, also I tried to find solutions for this on the web but lot of them ([the closest one is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10009651/error-when-building-the-website)) are working for IIS and not for VS 2012 IIS Express .

Please help me to get it running.