# Change location where .obj, .exe files are generated in visual studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

How do I change the location where .obj, .exe files are generated in visual studio?
I want these files to always be in a folder on the desktop

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261422/visualstudio-how-to-save-the-obj-folder-somewhere-else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the project properties, under Configuration Properties, you can set the Output directory and the intermediate directory.

Comment: Is there to do it globally for all solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your project's properties and look at the "General" tab under the "Configuration Properties". There you can change the Output Directory and Intermediate Directory.