# Avoiding CopyFilesToOutputDirectory build step

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

With my C# project in Visual Studio 2010, I noticed that msbuild compiles to a \obj directory, and then copies the files to the real output directory:

```
CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
Copying file from "obj\x86\Debug\Manager.exe" to "bin\Debug\Manager.exe".
```

There is no custom msbuild script, it's all the visual studio defaults. Is there any way to make it build directly to bin\Debug\Manager.exe; circumventing the "CopyFilesToOutputDirectory" step?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just wonder why do you want that. There is no easy way since by default obj folder is used when compiling the assemblies (executables and libraries). Only when it is successful the output is copied to bin folder. That is why is visual studio can successfully run the last successful build which is run from bin. So in essential there needs to be obj folder. You can extend the build mechanism, alter and tweak a bit by using this builder and not depending on the default builder by seeing [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43615/Genuilder)

Comment: The reason is that the build got much faster when I disabled "Copy Local", and I suspected that with such an option, another file copy could be avoided; therefore speeding up the build even more.

Comment: hmm, but what you're trying to tweak here is somethin the way visual studio works. I would say Do not

Comment: By default only updated files will be copied over, so that helps a little to finish the copy task faster.

Answer (score 3):

No there isn't, not really anyway. Because the obj folder is holding the temporary (not linked) files during the build.

More reading: [What are the obj and bin folders (created by Visual Studio) used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308491/what-are-the-obj-and-bin-folders-created-by-visual-studio-used-for)
and here: [VisualStudio: How to save the obj folder somewhere else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261422/visualstudio-how-to-save-the-obj-folder-somewhere-else)