# IDE compiler does not find dll in "obj" folder

Tags: vb.net, compiler-construction, ide

I am getting the error `"<somepath>\obj\x86\Debug\ucBrowser.dll" or one of its dependencies can't be found.`

I have not fully investigated what the real problem is, but I really wonder why the IDE would try to find something in the "\obj\x86..." folder.

I would like to have everything placed in one folder, not something in "\obj\", something in "\obj\x86", something in "\bin\x86\Debug". etc-

Can I get this straight?

Answer (score 0):

Would this help? [VisualStudio: How to save the obj folder somewhere else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261422/visualstudio-how-to-save-the-obj-folder-somewhere-else)

Basically you need to open .vbproj file and change the property BaseIntermediateOutputPath

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @MathiasMüller the essential parts are included.

Comment: @Kay This is a borderline case - I think this post is not enough to be an answer in its own right. Also, the question should be flagged as duplicate instead of referring to another SO question with a link.