# Do compilation files have to hit disk?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've read this question about [what the obj and bin folders are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308491/what-are-the-obj-and-bin-folders-created-by-visual-studio-used-for).

My APP/obj/CONFIGURATION folders contain hundreds of files. This includes a copy of every form (as a .resources file), icon, image (.bmp, .jpg, etc), multi-language translation file, and so on. The build takes up to three (painful!) minutes to complete.

- Do these intermediate files *have* to hit disk in this way?
- Can Visual Studio be configured to not hit disk with all these copies, but to link everything in memory?

This is a C#.NET application, if relevant.

Comment: Get an SSD. It'll make a huge difference.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Nice idea, but not immediately practical! :o)

Comment: Unfortunately you can't configure VS to do the build in memory.

Comment: I did small research for that and switched to building project to ramdisk and putting output of all projects to 1 folder, in my case it worked pretty well I'd say. You can also try linking files in output folders for your projects using MKLINK and "copy if newer" option, but that might be a  real pain

Comment: Can RAM disk be another option for you if SSD is not?

Comment: @MatthewWatson WRONG

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: Your comment is not constructive. Where exactly is Matthew wrong? If it is because you can create a RAM disk as per your answer, then perhaps mention that. I'm certainly here to learn...

Comment: @AlainD Well, when you emit a strong statement it should be because you're absolutely sure about you're talking about...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer It is the case that you cannot configure Visual Studio to do a build in memory. Of course you can use a RAM disk, but that's nothing to do with configuring Visual Studio. I am indeed absolutely certain that there is no configuration option in Visual Studio specifically for making it store intermediary compilation files in memory.

Comment: @MatthewWatson It would be wonderful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case I'm using [ImDisk](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/) to create a RAM disk, and then I instruct Visual Studio to put some temp files stored in the whole RAM disk (`M:` is the RAM disk's drive letter) using a simple BAT/CMD file:

```
set TEMP=M:\vstemp
set TMP=M:\vstemp
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
```

In the other hand, I've customized my build to point the `$(OutputPath)` to a directory in the RAM disk.

Also, I've found this other Q&A with info to change `obj` directory somewhere else: [VisualStudio: How to save the obj folder somewhere else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261422/visualstudio-how-to-save-the-obj-folder-somewhere-else).

Anyway, a solid-state disk boosts overall Visual Studio performance, and using both SSD+RAMDisk approach will avoid a lot of write operations to the SSD, which will increase its lifetime.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about ImDisk. The tool looks awesome just busy giving it a try now. Since it is not possible to ask Visual Studio to not output temporary linker files, the RAM disk seems like the way to go.

Comment: @AlainD Well, don't dream you'll be able to move everything to the RAMDisk. MSBuild still will hit the HDD/SSD, BTW, if you customize your build enough, you'll be able to more more than the 50% of created files to the RAM disk

Comment: Note that this will cause temp files produced by ALL programs to be written to the RAM disk. This will probably be fine unless some application tries to write a file bigger than your RAM disk, at which point you will get "out of disk space" errors.

Comment: @MatthewWatson AFAIK this isn't true, you're setting these environment variables for the process where they're being set. It does not affect other apps.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Just try it yourself. `SET TEMP` in a CMD and open another one, and try `ECHO %TEMP%`.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Ah yes, you're correct - I missed the crucial line in the batch file. :)

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: Quick question about the BAT/CMD you mention. Are you referring to something like a .bat file used to launch Visual Studio (eg. instead of opening VS directly using a Windows shortcut)?

Comment: @AlainD Yeah, that's it