# How to change the location of 'obj' folder in PackageReference

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I'm using [VisualStudio 2019 CE](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&rel=16) and [migrated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference) my .Net project from **packages.config** to **PackageReference**.

Now is it possible to change the path of the generated **obj** folder?

**Note:** I'm not talking about `<IntermediateOutputPath>` tag in build file.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to modify the location through PackageReference? The PackageReference just makes the whole package as reference in project. And as far as I know, there are no related configuration files for it.

Comment: @DylanZhu-MSFT When we build  the project, PackageReference generates a directory named `obj`. Next to the csproj build file.

Comment: The obj folder is created by nuget.exe because the some target/props files of package needs to be placed into it. Maybe you can create a post build event, then use `move [src] [dist]` to [move it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/move) or `rmdir /s /q $(ProjectDir)obj` to [remove it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/rmdir)

Comment: @DylanZhu-MSFT thanks, but by doing that, NuGet references completely will be removed from the project. IDK why! My prefer way is to set a path for it like  `<IntermediateOutputPath>` in my build file...

Comment: Could you use [Directory.Build.targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019) file with `<IntermediateOutputPath>` without modifying build file on your environment?

Comment: The solution mentioned in this issue worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63536867/completely-change-obj-folder-location-in-c-sharp-project